# removing python reference, copying instead

Tags: python, arrays, list, stack, byref

So I have a really strange error in this function I think it must have something to do with python references rather than value assignment. If anyone can see what is causing the value of mainList to disappear I would be very grateful. - http://pastebin.com/6sZCwAk8

```
inputs:
ships -> [0]
hitListLength = 1
output of first print statement [[0]]
output of second print statement [[]]
```

My theory is that because I have popped from the `countingList` it has removed the value from `mainList` not sure how to get round this?

```
def addPlacement(ships,hitListLength,start = None, mainList = None,countingList = None):
    if start == None:
        start=0
    if mainList == None:
        mainList = []
    if countingList == None:
        countingList = []
    #pop ship from array for use on this recusion level
    ship = ships.pop()
    #loop through each hit
    for x in range(start,hitListLength):
        #add this rotation to the counting list
        countingList.append(x)
        #if we don't need to go any deeper add the counting array as an element of the main list
        if len(ships) == 0:
            mainList.append(countingList)
            print "MainList: " + str(mainList)
        else:
            #otherwise recure deeper updating mainlist
            mainList += addPlacement(ships,hitListLength,(start+1),mainList,countinglist)
        #remove this loops countingList contribution so next loop can take its place
        countingList.pop()
    #return the mainlist
    ships.append(ship)
    print "MainList: " + str(mainList)
    return mainList
```

Comment: The way you do a deep copy is `newval = copy.deepcopy(oldval)`, but I'm not so sure that is the issue here.

Comment: changing mainlist.append(countingList) to mainlist.append(countingList[:]) i,e slicing the countingList should solve the problem of returning empty mainList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do

```
mainList.append(countingList)
```

and then

```
countingList.pop()
```

which removes only element from countingList which leaves you with [] in mainList

because append appends a reference to the countingList and you pop the only element from countingList this change gets reflected in mainList as well

use copy if you want to store a copy of countingList in mainList